# TemporaryFile in TemporaryDirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

In Python console, I'm trying to create `t = tempfile.TemporaryFile(dir=d.name)` where `d` is a `TemporaryDirectory`. Problem is `t` is not being created in `d`.

`d` has a name and all looks good

`t` is just invisible, I can do `t.write(b'hello')` but can't find the file in my `tempfile.gettempdir()`.

Comment: Documentation[https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfiles#tempfile.TemporaryFile] says that the TemporaryFile will be destroyed after closing tempfile - can you please show us the full snippet? I suppose that you can solve the problem using NamedTemporaryFile instead

Comment: I assumed it's all kept open since I'm running in Python Console and I can do .write(...). I don't call .close()  explicitly